# Error in loading a .mat file in jupyter notebook

Tags: matlab, jupyter-notebook, loading

I am facing a setback while loading a .mat file in jupyter notebook. Here's the issue encountered:

```
#import mat4py
from scipy.io import loadmat
mat = loadmat('Dog_1_ictal_segment_1.mat')
```

Error: `TypeError: Expecting miMATRIX type here, got 3225714032`

The mat file is downloaded from UPenn and Mayo's competition hosted at Kaggle, https://www.kaggle.com/c/seizure-detection/data.

I don't have access to the original matlab file, and I am not sure if the same was saved under v7.3+ release. Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: can you loadmat("sample_clip.mat")?

Comment: Done that. sample_clip.mat file loads however the others don't. Can the files be corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On matlab try:

```
fid = fopen('Dog_1_ictal_segment_1.mat');
txt = char(fread(fid,[1,140],'*char'));
fclose(fid);
disp(txt)
```

I get MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file for Patient_8_ictal_segment_1.mat (same competition). When using -v7.3 the header should start with MATLAB 7.3 MAT-file. I was able to load the data to python with no error using your code.
Possibly your data is corrupt, try downloading it.

Comment: It seems that the file got corrupted while extracting. With 7-zip extractor I was able to load the data.